# using sed to grep pattern from log file

Tags: sed, grep

I have the following log line

```
2021-10-28 10:26:19,624 INFO [Native-Thread-7f9e6effd700] idol.nifi.connector.GetWeb GetWeb[id=c59c415c-017c-1000-195c-e85818b0a032] Processing: [depth:0] https://qed.qld.gov.au/about-us/rti/disclosure-log/disclosure-log-2015
```

I want to extract the date and everything that comes after the word `Processing:` so that is looks like

```
2021-10-28 10:26:19 [depth:0] https://qed.qld.gov.au/about-us/rti/disclosure-log/disclosure-log-2015
```

I am not sure how to achieve this with grep or sed?

```
#!/bin/bash cat ./logs/*.log | grep Processing: | grep -E "(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)"
```

is as far as I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/,.*Processing://' file
```

Output:

```
2021-10-28 10:26:19 [depth:0] https://qed.qld.gov.au/about-us/rti/disclosure-log/disclosure-log-2015
```

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)